# Unintended consequence vs. side effect?

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference between these two?  Is one more relevant to technology having an impact on the human condition?

Answer (score 1):

In actual use, the intended meaning of these two phrases overlaps to the extent that you can't always tell the two apart.

However, "side effect" has a broader meaning. A "side effect" is just any effect that isn't the principal intended one.

For example, pharmaceuticals have "side effects" beyond the treatment of a patient's illness. Pharmaceutical companies are required to send a new drug through clinical trials before they are allowed to release it onto the market, and part of the reason for those trials is to determine what the side effects might be. They are also required to disclose the side effects, so that doctors and patients have a chance to know what they are and make an informed decision.

In programming, "side effect" has a specific meaning. See [this Software Engineering SE question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect).

This includes any input and output from the program. These "side effects" are very much **intended** consequences!

Comment: In my opinion it was a serious mistake for "side effect" to have been defined the way it was in computer programming because the definition is completely different to the plain English meaning of the term, indeed often it contradicts the plain English meaning. The programming meaning is important but should've been given some other name - too late to change it now though. In any case, note that in programming side effects aren't always intended, sometimes they're the result of programming errors (e.g.., when a function accidentally changes a global variable instead of a local one).

Comment: @nnnnnn there's a huge chance that *side effect* is a loan translation from latinate medical lingo; guess *para-*, which can translate "but, wither" as well as "besides, subsequent", so the ambiguity would be inherent. Indeed so in Greek, but *secondary*, *indesirable*, *collateral* in Sp, Fr, It--says en.wiktionary. Which says Gr *parenergia* were calqued from Ger *Nebenwirkung*; thus cp *by-product*

Comment: @nnnnnn - If a function accidentally changes a global variable that is not a side effect that is a bug.  If the function operates as designed and results in the global being changed, that's a side effect.

Comment: @Jim In the heyday of structured programming, where Pascal was the teaching language of choice, idempotency was considered a Good Thing, and any side effect got marked down as poor design. Imagine my shock when I first read the C++ standard to see them rehabilitated.

Comment: @Spencer - Yes, my first language was Fortran, my second was Pascal.  (Besides BASIC I guess)  but yeah, I remember when side-effects were frowned upon.  I was always pragmatic about it.  If it made sense then I did it and just commented it appropriately.

Comment: @Jim - Yes, you're right. Anyway, that wasn't my main point.